# Trouble receiving radiopacaket from Lora radio

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, uint8t, lora, lorawan

I am not able to receive the sent radio packet from the Lora rf95 transceiver.

I have tried declaring the received array as a char, uint8_t along with using len as size, however the size is 7 so i thought what I did was ok. It didn't recieve anything when I used:

```
uint8_t buf[RH_RF95_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
    uint8_t len = sizeof(buf);

    if (rf95.recv(buf, &len))
    {
      digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
      RH_RF95::printBuffer("Received: ", buf, len);
      Serial.print("Got: ");
      Serial.println((char*)buf);}
```

It does receive something at the same rate as the transceiver when I use:

```
uint8_t P;

if(rf95.recv((uint8_t*)P,7)){

  Serial.print((char)P);
Serial.println();
```

It prints the new line but no data. It was working before but when I started to try to adjust the power it no longer worked so I tried other things. I a new to coding so please don't be mean, I appreciate any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting a `uint8_t` to a `uint8_t*` this means that your **uninitalized** variable will be used to point to the location where `rf95.recv` is going to start storing its data. This means that if `P = 5` it will start at memory location `5` and if `P = 0` it will result in a `null` pointer.

What you should be doing is taking the address of `P`: `rf95.recv(&P,7))`.

As such these lines should be:

`rf95.recv(&buf, &len)`

`RH_RF95::printBuffer("Received: ", &buf, len);`

`Serial.println(buf[0]);`
or even better:

```
for(uint8_t i = 0; i<len; ++i) {
    Serial.println(buf[i]);
}
```

Your second code block wasn't printing out any data because `P` was uninitialized and probably containing the value `0`. So your received data was stored **at** address `0` instead of the address of the variable and as such wasn't changed by your receive because of the first pointer problem.